# customize View class adding an imageView dynamically

Tags: java, android, view

I have inherited a View class from an example zbar source code, but I need to add an ImageView to this View class, I don't have any xml layout file for this view, so how I can add this ImageView dynamically from code?

```
public class AndroidBarcodeView extends View
{
    static Context mContext;
    public AndroidBarcodeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
     AndroidBarcodeTestActivite myActivity = (AndroidBarcodeTestActivite) getContext();
        String id=myActivity.getString();


    try {

} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `View` to a `View`. You should extend from a `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `FrameLayout` or anything that extends from `ViewGroup`. There you can call `addView()`, where you can pass in an `ImageView`.

Regarding lay-outs, you might want to read this page from the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. That also explains what all those `*Layout` classes do.

That looks something like this (I copied your code and adapted it):

```
public class AndroidBarcodeView extends FrameLayout
{
    // static Context mContext; 
    // Please do not do this with a Context, as it might leak and you'll get memory problems
    // Also, the Context is available via getContext()

    private ImageView img;

    public AndroidBarcodeView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        ImageView img = new ImageView(context);
        addView(img); // This adds the ImageView to the ViewGroup
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        AndroidBarcodeTestActivite myActivity = (AndroidBarcodeTestActivite) getContext();
        String id=myActivity.getString();

        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```